# find nearest items from lat, lng in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My table contains lat and lng columns:

> lng | double precision | not null
>
> lat | double precision | not null

I want to retrieve only the results from a location (lat, lng).

How do I do ?

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: yes, I will post a response

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A much better way is, you can take help of `postgis` to create a separate geometry/geography column for geo-spatial queries.

`CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

`ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326);`

`UPDATE your_table SET geom=st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326);`

Once your table is updated you can do a simple nearest neighbor query like bellow.

`SELECT name FROM your_table ORDER BY geom <-> ST_GeomFromText ('POINT(-49.2653819 -25.4244287 )', 4326);`

Which will return nearest records to given points.

Comment: Can you please explain what the 4326 constant is?

Comment: its spatial reference id.
https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/projection.html

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it :

```
select * , ( point(lat, lng) <-> point($lat, $lng) )*111.325 AS distance
order by distance
```

you get the results ordered by the distance increasing and the distance is in kilometers.

Comment: Hi, may I know about 111.325 come from?

Comment: Sorry this is to far I can't remember where i found it but I know this is a constant, if I remember It it near the distance of 1 degree arround the earth

Comment: Multiplication is a linear operation, so the multiplication by 111.325 has no effect on the sort order. Also, 1 degree of latitude/longitude translates to different distances in different places on the earth -- you can't just calculate distance this way.

Comment: One can use pythagoras for short distances : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54249175/6661258

Comment: But I agree it's not very accurate