# How to get more precision for a computed distance in MySQL, without using geometric types?

Tags: mysql, precision, distance, latitude-longitude

I must compute the distance between an object (a city) and each of the several entries from a MySQL table I have (some restaurants). This city and the restaurants are located in a same country.

The computed distance is used in order to show all the restaurants which are close to this city ; the threshold distance is arbitrary. **Moreover, this is a ranked list: the closest restaurants are shown first, and the farest are shown at end-of-list.** My problem is about this ranking.

## What I've done for now

So I made some researches and I succeeded in computing this distance.

```
    $special_select_distance = "DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(" . $oneVilles->__get('latitude')[app::getLang()] . ")) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lon) - RADIANS(" . $oneVilles->__get('longitude')[app::getLang()] . ")) + SIN(RADIANS(" . $oneVilles->__get('latitude')[app::getLang()] . ")) * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))";

    $restaurants = $restaurantsDAO->getAll(null, ['distance DESC'] , null, 'HAVING distance < 1.9' , null , '*, ' . $special_select_distance . " AS distance");
```

... where:

1. `['distance DESC']` stands for the ranking by distance
2. `'HAVING distance < 1.9'` stands for the arbitrary threshold
3. `'*, ' . $special_select_distance . " AS distance"` is the selector
4. `$oneVilles->__get('latitude')[app::getLang()]` and `$oneVilles->__get('longitude')[app::getLang()]` are the city's coordinates lat and lon
5. `lat` and `lon` are the restaurant's coordinates (automatically taken into the table we are iterating on, *i.e.:* `restaurants` table, since we use the restaurants DAO)

## Question

### Actual and unexpected result

For each of the restaurants that are quite close between themselves, the computed distance with the city remains the same.

*Example: assume that restaurants A and B are quite close. Then, the distance between A and the city is the same than B and the city, it's my actual and unexpected result.*

**This is not what I want.** Indeed, in reality one of these restaurants is closest to the city than the other. I think there isn't enough precision in MySQL.

### Expected result

Expected result: to make the restaurants ranking according to the distance to the city working. In other words, to get a more precise computed distance.

*Example: assume that restaurants A and B are quite close. Then, the distance between A and the city is shorter than B and the city, it's my expected result.*

### Examples of computed distances

1. Between a restaurant and the city (the restaurant being far from the city):  `1.933156948976873`
2. Between a restaurant A and the city (A being close to the city): `1.6054631070094885`
3. Between a restaurant B and the city (B being close to A): `1.6054631070094885`

**Distances in points 2. and 3. are the same and it's not normal. I would want to have more digits, in order to be able to rank my restaurants more efficiently.**

## Constraints

- I wouldn't want to change the configuration of the MySQL Server.

  - **In particular: I absolutely can't use MySQL geometric types (it's a firm's constraint)**
- The expected solution should simply change the SQL query I wrote and provided to you, in order to be more precise, if it's possible.
- Other methods of calculating the distance are allowed, if necessary.

Comment: Can you explain how all of this is related to "precision"? Where do you take the distance between restaurants into account? With some example data and the real queries you are issuing, this might get more clear

Comment: The computed distances I gave you in examples are the same in points 2. and 3. However, in reality one of these restaurants is closer to the city than the other. I should have, for example: `1.60546310700948851` for A (notice the last digit I added) and `1.60546310700948852` for B (notice the last digit I added). So A is closer to the city than B. Either this lack of precision is due to the method of computing or to the storage, I don't know? Finally: the distance is takan account to rank the restaurants (cf. the SQL query, `getAll`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For long distances, use the Haversine formula for accuracy.  For short distances, Pythagoras is twice as fast.

16 significant digits (data type `DOUBLE`) is ludicrous.  You don't need to distinguish two different fleas on your dog.

With Pythagoras, be sure to divide the longitude by the cosine of the latitude -- One degree of longitude near Helsinki is half as far as one degree at the equator.

Some more details here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

If `1.6054631070094885` is a latitude diff, then think about it this way:  If you and I are at the same longitude, but our latitudes are 1.605463 and 1.605464, then, well, I don't know you well enough to be *that* close.

It is not practical to compare two floating point values without having a fudge factor:

```
If abs(a-b) < 0.00001, then treat them as equal.
```

**More**

I recommend `FLOAT` for lat, lng, and distance since you are talking about restaurants.  If you are not talking about more than, say, 100 miles or km, then this expression is sufficiently precise:

```
SQRT(  ($lat - lat) *
       ($lat - lat) +
      (($lng - lng) * COS(RADIANS(lat))) *
      (($lng - lng) * COS(RADIANS(lat))) )  * $factor
```

Where...

- `lat` and `lng` are names of `FLOAT` columns in the table, in units of degrees.
- `$lat` and `$lng` are values of the location you are starting from, also in degrees.  (PHP uses `$`; other languages use other conventions.)
- `$factor` is 69.172 for miles or 111.325 for kilometers.
- I would not display the result with more than perhaps 1 decimal place.  (Don't display "12.345678 miles"; "12.3 miles" is good enough.)

A **comparison** of Pythagoras and GCD:

```
             Pyt        GCD
To Rennes:  93.9407    93.6542
To Vannes:  95.6244    95.6241
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have no mathematical background. My firm just asked me to sort the restaurants according to their distance with the city. So concretly, I should use Pythagoras' formula? I will have to replace the value of ` $special_select_distance` (Haversine) with the Pythagoras and won't have anything more to do (such as modifying the MySQL configuration or the restaurants table etc.)?

Comment: Would it be possible to give me the new formula I should write please? I couldn't find it. Btw, would have I to increase the number of digits? In other words: how could I change the type `DOUBLE` to, e.g., `FLOAT` (which has more digits)? Indeed, `distance` is not a real column.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler - I added some.

Comment: It seems to work. However I'm facing with a problem. I have this SQL query: `SELECT *, SQRT((48.516667 - lat) * (48.516667 - lat) + ((-2.783333 - lon) / COS(RADIANS(lat))) * ((-2.783333 - lon) / COS(RADIANS(lat))) )  * 111,325 AS distance 
FROM restaurants 
WHERE 1=1 
AND visible = 1 
HAVING distance < 400 
ORDER BY distance DESC `. The result, shown in PHPMyAdmin, is that `distance` is always 325. **But** calculation varies from 211.1780761524938 (lot of restaurants) to 892.274765172128 (1 restaurant), going through 301.3392592046301 (2 restaurants) and 335.53948430743804 (1 restaurant).

Comment: Do you know why `distance` is always 325 while it should have the sames values than its calculation?

Comment: Don't use thousands-separators in numbers:  `...) * 111,325 AS distance ...`.  See the `325`?

Comment: Oh thank you. The framework we use has transformed my "." into a ","... Thanks. I have a math question about your formula. What type of result do we get finally? Is it a radius? If yes, are the lowest values the closest distances between restaurants to the city?

Comment: If I got the formula correct, smaller distances are restaurants closer to where you are in Saint-Brieuc.  Since the numbers are kilometers, `400` may be excessive.  You probably want `ORDER BY distance ASC` instead of `DESC`.

Comment: And. if you are using `111325`, you are measuring _meters_.  `111.325` is for _kilometers_.  So, maybe you did want 400m?

Comment: Yes, "radius".  Or "as the crow flies".  892 meters is likely to be 1400 meters after twisting and turning through the streets.  But geting the walking distance is far beyond the scope of MySQL.  You can, however, use a Google API, I think.

Comment: Mh, I don't think it's actually a radius, Rick! The query is now correct, look; `SELECT *, SQRT((48.51666700 - lat) * (48.51666700 - lat) + ((-2.78333300 - lon) / COS(RADIANS(lat))) * ((-2.78333300 - lon) / COS(RADIANS(lat))))  * 111.325 AS distance FROM restaurants WHERE 1=1 AND visible = 1 HAVING distance < 300 ORDER BY distance ASC `. **But I have strange results.** *Let a city, Saint-Brieuc, located at (48.51666700 ; -2.78333300 ).* Some found restaurants are located in Vannes (example for one: (47.6586438 ; -2.7543769))...

Comment: ...  Existing but **not found** restaurants are located in Rennes (example: (48.1164518 ; -1,6809908)). However, Saint-Brieuc is closer to Rennes than Vannes. In résumé: restaurants in Rennes should 1) be found and 2) be ranked before those of Vannes.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler - You asked for all restaurants within 400 (radius) km; Vannes is only 100 km away.  Rennes is a little closer; is it "visible"?  checking...

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler -- Sorry, I should have tested the formula before providing it.  It needs `*` instead of `/`.  I modified my Answer, and added a 'comparison' (using lat/lngs that I had handy, not yours).

Comment: Thank you, it works better! I still have some troubles to greatly sort my restaurants but it's out of range of this question :).